# How to show a UIButton inside a UIBarButtonItem? (with IB designed elements)

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

Most of the examples are along the lines of

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

But I like to work and design my UI with IB.

So I have a UIToolbar with a UIBarButtonItem on it,  and also a UIButton elsewhere on the form.

I would hope that

```
barbutton.customView = regularButton
```

would pass, and indeed in the debugger the custom view of the BarButtonItem now points to the regular button

But the button shows near the top of the form, not in the ToolBar!!??

Answer (score 1):

try by setting the bounds of the button you are adding as a customView.